# UDF Trigger not working MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, udf

Sarcastically enough the problem is that I am not getting any errors. The trigger is the following one:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER autohome1 
AFTER INSERT ON prueba
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 DECLARE cmd VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE result int(10);
 SET cmd=CONCAT('sh /home/pi/Desktop/Py_Script_Auto_Home/autohome.sh');
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

If I am not wrong (I dont know much about this topic), whenever I insert into the table named "prueba", the command should be executed. Or at least that is what I understand this should do, However this is not happening. I am not clear about the functionality of the line "SET result = sys_exec(cmd);"

I know that the command I want to execute works so I do not know from where should I start tackling my problem.

Comment: Try and change the cmd to something simple to say 'touch /tmp/hello.txt', just to see if the script is doing anything.

Comment: So I tried it with the "touch" command and it worked. However when I try my command from command line it also works, so I do not know why it's not working in the trigger. Thank you

Comment: OK - if you check the owner of the file it creates,make sure that this user has permissions to access the script your trying to run.

Comment: So I checked and the user who created it is "mysql". After that I did "chown mysql: /home/pi/Desktop/Py_Script_Auto_Home/autohome.sh" and then "chmod u+x /home/pi/Desktop/Py_Script_Auto_Home/autohome.sh". But its still not working...

Comment: It may be access to the directory, can yo move the script to /tmp and see if it runs from there.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have checked all the permissions and they seem to be okay: "-rwxrwx--x 1 mysql mysql 25 May 29 22:20 /tmp/newscript1.sh" I don't know where else could be the error. Is there any code I can provide to make it simpler for you to help me?